# Raspberry Pi install screen - Internal Error, ordering was unable to handle the media swap

Tags: linux

I am trying to install `screen` in my Raspberry Pi. If I run `sudo apt-get install screen`, I get the following error:

```
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

However, if I run `sudo apt-get install screen --fix-missing`, I get this error:

```
E: Internal Error, ordering was unable to handle the media swap
```

I already tried `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get update`, but none of those commands changed the errors. Any suggestions? I am running Linux raspberrypi 3.18.7+.

Comment: try `sudo apt-get update -y && sudo apt-get upgrade -y && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y && sudo apt-get install screen`

Comment: I tried that, got the same errors =/

Comment: did you try the `dist-upgrade`? it sounds like you have a broken mirror, and that's why apt is failing. it could be temporary, or it could be you have a very old list of mirrors. Does it do it with any other programs you try to install?

Comment: Yes, I tried `dist-upgrade` as well, nothing changed

Comment: Does it do it with any other programs you try to install? Have you tried `sudo apt-get clean`?

Comment: @SnakeDoc, not that I know of - I installed some other programs and got no error. Also, `apt-get clean` didn't change anything

Comment: I'm fairly certain this is just a broken mirror that's giving you issues. There was a similar issue with another app here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/1722  It may just clear itself up after a while. Basically it looks like the server is up, so apt tries to download the file, but partway through the download, the server cuts the connection. so apt freaks out...

Comment: Here's another related issue, with more cmd's to try out: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/628

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem. I manually downloaded the package screen_4.5.0-6_armhf.deb from http://raspbian.mirror.net.in/raspbian/raspbian/pool/main/s/screen/screen_4.5.0-6_armhf.deb.

Then I pasted the file in the pi and fired up my terminal.
The with the command sudo dpkg -i /path/to/the/file 
That's it...